# node.js prompt: how to disable the appearance of the property name?

Tags: node.js, prompt

I wrote the following code using 'prompt' package. I defined:

```
message: ''
```

in order to disable the appearance of the property name 'username' in console whenever the program waits for the user to give an input.

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.message = '';
var schema = {
   properties: {
      username: {
         message: ''
      }
   }
};
console.log('Please type your username');
prompt.get(schema, function(err, result) {
   console.log('Command-line input received:');
   console.log('username is ' + result.username);
})
```

Still, it doesn't work out and the console prints:

> Please type your username
>
> **username**: myname Command-line input
>
> received: username is myname

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `description: ''` instead of `message: ''`.

There appears to be erroneous documentation about this:

> The basic structure of a prompt is this:
>
> ```
> prompt.message + prompt.delimiter + property.message + prompt.delimiter;
> ```

But this is not correct; `property.message` is used to explain a validation error, not appear in a prompt. Earlier in the documentation, it says (correctly) of `description` and `message`:

```
{
  description: 'Enter your password',  // Prompt displayed to the user. If not supplied name will be used.
  ...
  message: 'Password must be letters', // Warning message to display if validation fails.
  ...
}
```

Comment: I changed 'message' to 'description' and it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @CrazySynthax Just to check, what happens if you supply a non-empty value for `description`, like `description: "foo"`? Does it show `foo` or still only the original property name?